# Set max number of Outbound Requests Programatically (System.Net) rather than App.Config

Tags: c#, app-config

I know I can add the following to a client to handle a higher volume of outbound requests:

```
  <system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
      <add address="*" maxconnection="65535" />
    </connectionManagement>
  </system.net>
```

Is there a way to do this in code, not in the app.config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
        Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/YourSiteRoot");
        ConnectionManagementSection connectionManagementSection =
            (ConnectionManagementSection)config.GetSection("system.net/connectionManagement");

        connectionManagementSection.ConnectionManagement.Add(new ConnectionManagementElement("*", 65535));

        if (config.HasFile)
            config.Save();
```

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work.  The code runs fine, but the App.Config file is unchanged.  I have tried a few different tutorials and articles I found on Google - but no luck.   Keep in mind that I may need to add the entire '<system.net>' section.

Comment: Ok ... my mistake - I am in a Windows application, not web.  It wasn't changing my app config file because I was looking at the wrong one (I was looking at the one in my project, not the one in my Debug folder).